# 1366x768 to FHD TV is 1080p or not?

Tags: laptop, display, resolution, conversion

I was thinking to buy a new laptop with 1366x768 resolution. I like watching movies on my laptop and I want to connect it to my FHD TV and watch some movies on 1080p. Will I be able to do that even if the screen of the laptop is not 1080p.

Comment: This depends on the graphics card in the laptop and the types of connector available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if the movie is of HD resolution, you can connect it to an FHD TV and see it in 1920x1080 glory. All that is required is for the laptop to be ***capable*** of outputting FHD video -- resolution of the screen doesn't matter.

Comment: If it answers your questions, please choose it as the correct answer and/or upvote :)

Comment: I've a laptop with 1366x768 res and it doesn't output in FHD.